# Are there federal murder offenses that do not involve interstate activity in the United States?

Tags: united-states, us-federal-government, murder, us-states

When one commits the crime of murder in a single state of the United States, does he also violate a federal law against murder, or does it only become a federal crime if the murderer crosses state lines and commits murder in multiple states?

Answer (score 10):

Many of the federal laws against murder involve the murder of a federal official, such as the President or a postal worker. In those cases, the murder is both a state offense and a federal offense.

There are also other federal murder offenses that do not involve interstate activity.

Comment: "_There are also other federal murder offenses that do not involve interstate activity._" Could you please elaborate on that? That's what I'm interested in (not murdering federal officials).

Comment: @Geremia There are more examples at https://www.greenspunlaw.com/library/when-murder-is-a-federal-crime.cfm#:~:text=The%20United%20States%20government%20may,minor%20children%20are%20federal%20crimes. such as a murder committed to try to influence the outcome of a federal court case, a murder committed during a bank robbery, a murder related to rape, child molestation, or the sexual exploitation of children, drug-related murders, murders by mail, and terrorism related murders (as well as murders on Indian reservations, as noted).

Comment: Murders committed on military bases or inside the buildings of federal agencies.

Comment: @nick012000 Good catch.

Comment: @nick012000 For the same reason, murders committed in federal parks or on any federal land, of which there is a lot.